# ulti-cohort longitudinal panel data: how to apply weights to models that incorporate variables from different years?

Tags: panel-data, survey-weights

I'm running Stata 15.1 on OSX. The dataset in question comes from [The American Panel Survey](http://taps.wustl.edu/) in which three cohorts of participants filled out surveys each month (some of which measured the same items) between the years 2012-2016. The specific question I have is which weights to use--and how to apply them--when specifying regression models that utilize variables from different years. Each monthly wave of the survey has its [own](http://taps.wustl.edu/files/taps/imce/technical_report-2013-2.pdf) weight. Thus, if my dependent and independent variables are taken from February 2013 and July 2016 surveys, respectively, which weights should I use? My (likely faulty) intuition suspects the weights should be combined...but I really don't have a clue whether that's appropriate or how to do so. For whatever reason, the data didn't come much instructive documentation, so I really don't how to proceed. Any guidance will be much appreciated here. Thanks in advance!